# Altium: Add component layer pair vs add mechanical layer

Tags: altium

Altium designer provides these two options to add new layers into the view configuration:

[image]

The default use layers that really matter for PCB manufacture are already present in the program by default. This is the top and bottom, overlay, paste and solder. These raises the following questions:

1. Why would anyone need to add more layers.
2. What decides which of the two methods are used to add the new layer.
3. Why is there some overlap in the two sides with both containing assembly and dimentions in the list?
4. Why are we only able to add only two type of layers which are "Component Layer Pairs (C)" and "Mechanical Layers (M)"?

EDIT:
This question is very specifically about PCB foot prints.

Comment: "top and bottom", but what about four+ layer PCBs? That's a good reason to add more layers. What if you want to add annotations about things like transmission line impedances that might need adjusting if the PCB stackup is ever changed? What about edge connectors with gold fingers, where you need to annotate that this one part of the board is plated with hard gold, but not the entire board (because no one can afford that)? What if your assembly house requires information about part positioning? What if you're doing carbon-mask resistors? There are countless reasons you might need more layers.

Comment: This question is specifically about PCB foot prints. I will have to learn about each of these reasons that you have given.

Comment: I know that PCB can have multiple physical layers for signal and power and other things like silk screen, solder mask, solder paste e.t.c. However, there are many layers in Altium that do not carry any data relevant to the actual manufacture process. This e.g includes the mechanical layer that contains the 3D model of the components which is usually the mechanical layer 1.

Comment: Strange that we're getting a bunch of Atlium questions.  Is there something wrong with the actual Altium forum (where there are many, many more Altium users)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would anyone need to add more layers.

Typically for documentation. For example,

- A layer with lines showing how close a connector must be to the board edge.
- A layer with boxes drawn around each component showing how close it can be placed to other components (a "courtyard" layer, which is built in to many layout tools but not to Altium, at least when I last used it)
- A layer showing where special manufacturing operations are to be applied, like gold plating or milling operations
- A layer showing how the board will be panelized

> What decides which of the two methods are used to add the new layer.

Do you need separate copies of this layer for top and bottom components (for example for courtyard layers) or not (for example, for edge plating drawings)?

> Why is there some overlap in the two sides with both containing assembly and dimentions in the list?

Because Altium figures some designers (for example, designers working on signle-sided boards) might want only one of those types of layers and other designers might want one for each side.

These names don't affect the behavior of the tool, they just change what name is given to the layer in the various UI elements.

> Why are we only able to add only two type of layers which are "Component Layer Pairs (C)" and "Mechanical Layers (M)"?

Because those are Altium's names for general purpose layers that you can do whatever you want with. All of the other layer types are ones that Altium has pre-defined what their purpose is and how they are used.

And of course you *can* add additional signal and plane copper layers as you need them, you just use a different dialog to do it.

Comment: Thanks. This question is specifically about the PCB footprint design of components. How would a person know whether a new custom layer should go into "Component Layer Pairs (C)" and "Mechanical Layers (M)"?

Comment: @guunyuu, you need to decide on a standard for your project(s) of how the mechanical layers will be used, and then make your parts library to fit that choice. For example if you decide that mechanical layers 1 and 2 will be used for top and bottom courtyard layers, you build your library with those as a layer pair, and put the appropriate data on mech 1 in your library parts.

Comment: If it hasn't changed in the last 3 years, you don't even have to designate which layers are pairs in the library. When you bring the part into the design, the design will determine which layers are pairs and if you have some data on mech layer 1, and mech layer 2 is paired with it in the design, the data will be flipped to layer 2 if you move the part to the bottom of the board.

Comment: I saw someone use layer pairs for 3D body, component center, courtyard, designator, overlay, paste, polarity and solder. I am not sure which of these layer pairs already existed by default. Now the confusing part is, why use layer pairs for all this, can't Altium just figure out that if the component is made upside down, then the data that was on top *side*, goes to bottom *side*? Why bother with creating so many layer pairs and not just single layers?

Comment: Also, when I use the Altium "IPC Compliant Footprint Wizard" or "Footprint Wizard", neither of them create a footprint that has layer pairs for things like courtyard, 3D body, assembly e.t.c. This is very confusing actually.

Comment: @quantum231, Altium can't just "figure it out" because mechanical layers aren't associated with the top or bottom until you make a layer pair. And if it did "just move it to the bottom" it wouldn't know which layer to use for the bottom for that kind of information until you create the layer pair.

Comment: The Wizard doesn't do this because layer pairs are to allow you to customize the tool to work with your design process and manufacturing process, not something that is pre-determined by a standard.

Comment: OK, so if I create a layer pair lets say for assembly or courtyard, do I just add information into one of them and it is repeated in both of them automatically? Or, do I add information explicitly into both of them?

Comment: It's entered into whichever one you put it in. If it's part of a footprint and you flip the part to the other side, it moves to the paired layer.